# C pragma "-Wunused-variable" not working on Ubuntu

Tags: c, pragma

We have a C code which we build on both windows 7 and linux ubuntu.
To suppress unused variable errors we are using

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
```

But this flag works on windows but on ubuntu this is not working.
We are using ubuntu gcc versio

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Any hint as how to get unused-variable flag work on linux?

Comment: Works with [gcc 5.4 as expected](https://godbolt.org/z/qhj9hb). Are you actually compiling with gcc and not with some other compiler? OTOH, why not fix the warnings (i.e. clean up the unused vars)?

Comment: We are compiling with GCC. Removing unused variables is not direct option as the variables are defined in client header files which we are not allowed to change and when we include those header files we get unused variables errors.
So we thought of suppress the warning.

Comment: Ok. But I can't reproduce it. The gcc 5.4 doc says that it should work as expected. The reason I asked if it's really gcc is that the *name* might be gcc but other similar compiler might be used (e.g. clang or icc) with a symlink. Can you reproduce it with a small program on your system?

Comment: Why are variables defined in header files at all? This is clearly an error.